# Starting Minikube with Docker driver and bind it to host network

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I was wondering if it was possible to bind my minikube network to my `host` network.

I tried:

```
minikube start --memory=10000 --cpus=4 --vm-driver=docker --kubernetes-version=v1.19.6 --mount --mount-string="/usr/local/citizennet/db:/usr/local/citizennet/db" --network="host"
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
❗  Unable to create dedicated network, this might result in cluster IP change after restart: un-retryable: create network host 192.168.49.0/24: docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=192.168.49.0/24 --gateway=192.168.49.1 -o --ip-masq -o --icc -o com.docker.network.driver.mtu=1500 --label=created_by.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=true host: exit status 1
stdout:

stderr:
Error response from daemon: operation is not permitted on predefined host network
```

I was able to do that by using `haproxy` but I would like to know if there is a cleaner way of doing that.
My minikube is hosted on an EC2 instance and I would like to forward everything to my minikube directly. Or at least the HTTP/HTTPS requests.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, have you tried to use `$ minikube start --driver=none`? It uses Docker to spawn all the Kubernetes resources directly on your `VM`. You can read more about it by following this documentation: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/none/

Comment: Hi @DawidKruk, the problem is that I want to use the `ingress` addon and this addon is not compatible anymore with `--driver=none`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found a way to expose the `minikube` instance with `--driver=docker` to the host network (apart from `$ kubectl port-forward svc/svc-name --address=0.0.0.0 local_port:pod_port` ran on the host).

It produces the same error as original poster is experiencing:

```
Error response from daemon: operation is not permitted on predefined host network
```

Acknowledging following comment:

> the problem is that I want to use the `ingress` addon and this addon is not compatible anymore with `--driver=none`.

Instead of using `--driver=docker` which will place all of the resources in the Docker container, you can opt for a `--driver=none` which will provision all of your resources directly on the `VM`. You will be able to directly query the resources from other network devices.

For now `minikube` version `v1.17.1` does not allow to use the `ingress` addon with `--driver=none` but I found a way it could be provisioned. I've included this example on the end of this answer. Please treat this as a workaround.

**This issue (inability to use `ingress` addon on `--driver=none`) is already addressed on github**:

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Minikube: Issues: Ingress addon stopped to work with 'none' VM driver starting from v1.12.x](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/9322)*

---

Talking from the perspective of exposing `minikube`:

**As it's intended for accessing from external sources, I do recommend trying out other solutions that will subjectively speaking have easier time exposing your workloads to the external sources.** There are many available tools that spawn Kubernetes clusters and you can look which suits your needs the most. **Some** of them are:

- *[Kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/)*
- *[Kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray)*
- *[MicroK8S](https://microk8s.io/)*

---

### Deploying `nginx-ingress` with `minikube --driver=none`

As stated previously, please treat it as a workaround.

> A side note!
>
> Take a look on how your `NGINX Ingress` controller is configured with `minikube addons enable ingress` as it will be pretty much mimicked in this example.

Steps:

- `Download` the `nginx-ingress` `YAML` manifest:

  - Modify the `Deployment` in the manifest
  - Delete the `Service` from manifest
- Apply and check

#### `Download` the `nginx-ingress` `YAML` manifest

You can use following manifest:

- *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress Nginx: Deploy](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)* (for example `GKE` manifest could be downloaded)

#### Modify the `Deployment` in the manifest

As I said previously, what is happening when you run `minikube addons enable ingress` could prove useful. The resources deployed have some clues on how you need to modify it.

- Add the `hostPort` for `HTTP` and `HTTPS` communication:

```yaml
          ports:
            - name: http
              hostPort: 80 # <-- IMPORTANT, ADD THIS
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: https
              hostPort: 443 # <-- IMPORTANT, ADD THIS
              containerPort: 443
              protocol: TCP
            - name: webhook
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
```

- Delete the `--publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller`:

```yaml
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller # <-- DELETE THIS
            - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
            - --ingress-class=nginx
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --validating-webhook=:8443
            - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
            - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
```

#### Delete the `Service` from manifest

You will need to entirely delete the `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` named:  `ingress-nginx` from the manifest as you will already be using `hostPort`.

After this steps you should be able to use `Ingress` resources and communicate with them on `VM_IP`:`80`/`443`.

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)*
- *[Minikube.sigs.k8s.io: Docs: Drivers: None](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/none/)*

Comment: Thank you so much!