# Expose Server Nginx via Minikube installed with Virtual Box in bridge mode

Tags: nginx, virtualbox, minikube

in short, for a project i should expose an nginx server with minikube installed via virtual box and i should expose it in bridge mode but unfortunately the server is always exposed via the vbnet0 virtual interface, if i try to manually modify in the virtual box network settings, minikube gets stuck and I can't do anything anymore.
Do you have any advice?
Thanks so much for the support,
Best regards,
Corrado

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to consider here:

- Use `minikube start --driver=virtualbox` with some additional [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62697373/11560878). Notice the `Virtualbox` part of the answer.
- Use `minikube start --driver=none` **on the VM** alongside with `nginx-ingress` like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66419813/11560878).

Both ways are explained in detail by a great community member @DawidKruk. You can find both cases below:

- [Expose Kubernetes cluster to Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62559281/expose-kubernetes-cluster-to-internet/62697373)
- [Starting Minikube with Docker driver and bind it to host network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66378335/starting-minikube-with-docker-driver-and-bind-it-to-host-network/66419813)