# access minikube cluster on the same network

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, networking, ip, minikube

I've set up a `minikube` cluster for development purpose inside a VM.
I've deployed few services and an ingress controller (the minikube one) to be able to access it without using NodePorts.
Inside my VM, I can access my services as usual with `curl http://hello-world.info` or another one. Everything works fine.

But when I'm outside of my VM, I can't access it even if I'm on the same network. I tried from my hosting server, from my laptop and outside with a VPN.
The cluster IP is well listed in my addresses inside the VM (`ip a`), but not accessible outside of it (e.g: `ping xxx`).
How can I access my cluster services on another machine inside the same network ?

My VM's IP is set to static (`ubuntu-server 20.XX.XX`) with netplan at `192.168.1.128` and my cluster IP is `192.168.49.2`. My DHCP server is allowed to distribute IPs only between `192.168.1.101-254`.

Thanks :).

Comment: How is the VM connected to the outside world? Does it use NAT? Is it bridged to a real adapter?

Comment: Don't know if that answer your question, but the VM is using a network bridge (br0) with a virtio-net driver.

Comment: @DataHearth Hello, could you please tell which `--driver` you are using with minikube? Do I assume correctly that is a `virtualbox` driver?

Comment: @DawidKruk I'm using the docker driver :). After some research, the virtualbox driver seems a little less restrictive for me. So I'll maybe give it a try.

Comment: Speaking from my own experience, the easiest way to expose `minikube` to your `LAN` is with either `virtualbox` or `none` driver. There are also other options outside of `minikube` that should be easier. It all depends on your requirements. I've already answered similar question, have you seen them by any chance [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62559281/expose-kubernetes-cluster-to-internet/62697373#62697373), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66378335/starting-minikube-with-docker-driver-and-bind-it-to-host-network/66419813#66419813) (specifically the part of `--driver=none`)?

Comment: @DawidKruk thanks for the tips. That was my problem in this case. I used the docker driver by default because I wasn’t aware of that « issue ». That’s, in my case, a better option to use the other drivers you listed than docker :). You can post it as an answer . Thanks buddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I haven't found a way to expose `minikube` instance with `--driver=docker` on `LAN`.

As a workaround to expose your `minikube` instance on `LAN` you can either `--driver`:

- `--driver=virtualbox`
- `--driver=none`

Being specific to the exposing your Kubernetes cluster to `LAN`, I would also consider checking out other Kubernetes solutions like (you could run them on bare-metal or run them in a vbox vm with `bridged` networking:

- [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/)
- [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray)
- [microk8s](https://microk8s.io/)

---

#### `--driver=virtualbox`:

Citing part of my own answer some time ago:

> As I previously mentioned: When you create your `minikube` instance with Virtualbox you will create below network interfaces:
>
> - `NAT`-  interface which will allow your VM to access the Internet. This connection cannot be used to expose your services
> - `Host-only-network-adapter` - interface created by your host which allows to communicate within the interface. It means that your host and other vm's with this particular adapter could connect with each other. It's designed for internal usage.
>
> You can read more about Virtualbox networking here:
>
> - [Virtualbox.org: Virtual Networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)
>
> I've managed to find a **workaround** to allow connections outside your laptop/pc to your `minikube` instance. You will need to change network interface in settings of your `minikube` instance from  **`Host-only-network-adapter`** to **`Bridged Adapter`** (2nd adapter). This will work as another device was connected to your physical network. Please make sure that this bridged adapter is used with Ethernet NIC. `Minikube` should change IP address to match the one used in your physical one.
>
> > You will also need to change your `.kube/config` as it will have the old/wrong IP address!
>
> After that you should be able to connect to your `Ingress` resource by IP accessible in your physical network.
>
> -- *[Stackoverflow.com: Answers:: Expose Kubernetes cluster to Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62559281/expose-kubernetes-cluster-to-internet/62697373#62697373)*

---

#### `--driver=none`

You can also run `minikube` with `--driver=none` but there are some caveats to this method which you can read more about by following this docs (tl;dr you are running your `minikube` directly on your host):

- *[Minikube.sigs.k8s.io: Docs: Drivers: None](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/none/)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Minikube.sigs.k8s.io: Docs: Drivers](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/)*

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround - instead of getting minikube/docker/whatever to listen on one of my machines interfaces I route traffic from a port to my minikube instance:port with iptables

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 50000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.58.2:80
```

--dport is the port on my machine that receives traffic from the lan.

In order to access the minikube system I go to http://hostmachine:50000