# Minikube running in Docker, and port forwarding

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, portforwarding

I'm pretty well versed in Docker, but I haven't got Minikube/K8s working yet. I first tried setting up artifactory-oss in helm but failed to connect to the LoadBalancer. Now I'm just trying the [basic hello-minikube NodePort setup as a sanity check](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/).

When I do `minikube start`, it starts up minikube in Docker:

```
> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS          PORTS                                                                                                                                  NAMES
ebabea521ffe   gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.18   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   2 weeks ago   Up 36 minutes   127.0.0.1:49167->22/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49166->2376/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49165->5000/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49164->8443/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49163->32443/tcp   minikube
```

So Minikube only has ports 4916(3/4/5/6/7) open?

So I installed hello-minikube:

```
> kubectl create deployment hello-minikube --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4
> kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube --type=NodePort --port=8080



> minikube ip
192.168.49.2


> minikube service list
|----------------------|------------------------------------|--------------|---------------------------|
|      NAMESPACE       |                NAME                | TARGET PORT  |            URL            |
|----------------------|------------------------------------|--------------|---------------------------|
| default              | hello-minikube                     |         8080 | http://192.168.49.2:30652 |
| default              | kubernetes                         | No node port |
| kube-system          | ingress-nginx-controller-admission | No node port |
| kube-system          | kube-dns                           | No node port |
| kubernetes-dashboard | dashboard-metrics-scraper          | No node port |
| kubernetes-dashboard | kubernetes-dashboard               | No node port |
|----------------------|------------------------------------|--------------|---------------------------|

> minikube service --url hello-minikube
http://192.168.49.2:30652
```

I check firewall, and it has the ports I've opened:

```
> sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens192
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 8000-9000/tcp 30000-35000/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

> kubectl get pods
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hello-minikube-6ddfcc9757-hxxmf   1/1     Running   0          40m

> kubectl get svc
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
hello-minikube   NodePort    10.97.233.42   <none>        8080:30652/TCP   36m
kubernetes       ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          19d

> kubectl describe services hello-minikube
Name:                     hello-minikube
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=hello-minikube
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=hello-minikube
Type:                     NodePort
IP Families:              <none>
IP:                       10.97.233.42
IPs:                      10.97.233.42
Port:                     <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30652/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.6:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

I've tried every IP and port combination, `minikube tunnel`, and `kube proxy` and a few other things but I just can't find any port to access this service from another machine.  I can't get an 'External-IP'.  nmap finds a bunch of ports if i search from the machine itself.

```
> nmap -p 1-65000 localhost

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2021-04-26 15:16 SAST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0013s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 64971 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
25/tcp    open  smtp
80/tcp    open  http
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
443/tcp   open  https
631/tcp   open  ipp
3000/tcp  open  ppp
5000/tcp  open  upnp
5050/tcp  open  mmcc
8060/tcp  open  unknown
8080/tcp  open  http-proxy
8082/tcp  open  blackice-alerts
9090/tcp  open  zeus-admin
9093/tcp  open  unknown
9094/tcp  open  unknown
9100/tcp  open  jetdirect
9121/tcp  open  unknown
9168/tcp  open  unknown
9187/tcp  open  unknown
9229/tcp  open  unknown
9236/tcp  open  unknown
33757/tcp open  unknown
35916/tcp open  unknown
41266/tcp open  unknown
49163/tcp open  unknown
49164/tcp open  unknown
49165/tcp open  unknown
49166/tcp open  unknown
49167/tcp open  unknown
```

But if I scan that machine from another machine on the network:

```
> nmap -p 1-65000 10.20.2.26

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2021-04-26 15:23 SAST
Nmap scan report for 10.20.2.26
Host is up (0.00032s latency).
Not shown: 58995 filtered ports, 6001 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
8060/tcp open  unknown
```

those ports don't seem to be accessible.  Any ideas?

-- EDIT 1:
The sys admin says only `10.20.x.x` IPs will resolve.  So `192.168.x.x` and `10.96.x.x` won't work.  So perhaps this `--service-cluster-ip-range` field is what I'm looking for.  I will try it out next.

Comment: `I just can't find any port to access this service from another machine` As far as I know that might not work when you use docker driver, it's better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66873437/access-minikube-cluster-on-the-same-network/66945182#66945182). So my suggestion would be to use another driver(e.g. virtualbox, none).

Comment: thanks that looks very relevant, I'll confirm tomorrow.  Makes sense that minikube in a docker will have port issues

Comment: Yeah, had sysadmin assign a secondary IP to the machine, and used that, and still can't get anything to connect.  Had problems with virtualbox before inside vmware, so just gonna scrap Kubernetes for now.  Back to Docker.  Thanks anyway

Comment: Hey Wiktor, I asked the question 5 months ago, and just went back to using a load balancer and Docker., at the time.  There's no issues in production with our existing setup, so checking out K8s was just R&D.  I'm sure I'll get around to trying again, in the next year or so, and will report back when I do.  But probably not going to try again any time soon.  My off-hand prediction is that the solutions below don't work, as I would have tried virtualbox, and port forwarding.  But maybe. I missed something.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue that I was banging my head upon, [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) was quite helpful. In my case I was accessing a Jenkins build server running in a Kubernetes cluster via minikube on my Mac OS.

I followed steps to get this port forwarding working:

1. Confirm the port of your pod :

   `kubectl get pod <podname-f5d-48kbr> --template='{{(index (index .spec.containers 0).ports 0).containerPort}}{{"\n"}}' -n <namespace-name>`

Say the output displays

```
> 27013
```

2. Forward a local port to a port on the Pod like so :

`kubectl port-forward <podname-deployment-f5db75f7-48kbr> 8080:27013 -n <namespace-name>`

and that should start the port forwarding, the output like :

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 27013
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 27013
```

now access your application on the browser via http://localhost:8080/

Comment: This doesn't work on minikube with docker driver.

Answer (score 0):

Posted community wiki for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

---

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66873437/access-minikube-cluster-on-the-same-network/66945182#66945182) answer.

Seems there is no possibility to access minikube cluster setup with `--driver=docker` **from the other host in the same local network.**

The workaround is to use other driver while setting up minikube cluster:

- `--driver=virtualbox` (recommended) -> use `Bridged Adapter` setting
- `--driver=none` (potential issues)

For more details (how to setup etc.) please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66873437/access-minikube-cluster-on-the-same-network/66945182#66945182) answer.